# cordova 3.5 w/ notification.prompt on android 2.3.3

Tags: android, notifications, cordova-plugins, navigator

The navigator.notification.prompt is not working on android v2.3.3 (tested on motorola droid2 global).  The code runs without throwing an error, but the prompt does not appear on the screen.  The same app code runs fine on v4.1.2 (tested on samsung sch-1200).  Any thoughts what could be preventing the prompt under v2.3.3?

I have checked cordova.apache.org docs and there is no mention of being version specific.  I've also tried the other notification methods without luck.

Here is my code:

```
console.log('before notification prompt');
try {

    navigator.notification.prompt(
            'Enter the new Category',  // message
            onNewCategory,         // callback
            'Categories',            // title
            ['Save', 'Cancel'],       // buttons
            ''                     // default text
            );

}
catch (e) {
    console.error(e.message);
}
console.log('after notification prompt');
```

The console output shows that it ran normally with no error.

'Cordova plugin ls' shows the plugin is successfully installed.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This noted issue with the dialogs plugin has now been fixed and merged on to the [dialogs repository](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-dialogs/pull/31). Hopefully this should be available in the next release of the plugin.

A possible workaround until this is released would be to replace the contents of `Notification.java` in `platforms\android\src\org\apache\cordova\dialogs\` with [this commit](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-dialogs/commit/4cfe290b2a3e8f0aafb71a1ff4fbee4b710c8749) contents.

Comment: Having only started to play with Cordova at v3.3 and using more seriously since 3.5, is this an issue that never worked, or worked then broke with the later version? Since I'm new to the product, I'm trying to evaluate at the same time the stability of this nice cross-platform product.  If it turns out that it's not stable enough for production environments, maybe I need to reconsider it's use.  I realize 2.3.3 is getting old and the user base is shrinking, but it was major when phonegap first started and this is a very basic feature.  This along with FileApi bugs with wp8 make me question it.